# WIX CustomAction - how to get more info in install/log

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Someone told me there was a way for the CustomAction in WIX to display the output in the console log.  I'm including an .exe called XmlPreprocess.exe to manipulate my web.config, based on parms in a file called SettingsFileGenerator.xml,

I'm running like this: 
msiexec /i bin\Debug\TFBIC.RCT.WCFWebServicesWIXSetup.msi  /L*V "C:\logs\WixInstall01.log"

This is my WIX build file:

```
 <CustomAction Id="**SAMPLE_CONFIG**" BinaryKey="XMLPREPROCESS" ExeCommand="/i:&quot;[INSTALLLOCATION]web.config&quot; /x:&quot;[INSTALLLOCATION]SettingsFileGenerator.xml&quot; /e:QA /d:ServiceLocation=[SERVICELOCATION]" Execute="deferred" />
    <Binary Id="XMLPREPROCESS" SourceFile="../TFBIC.RCT.WCFWebServices/RequiredBins/XMLPreprocess.exe" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SAMPLE_CONFIG" After="StartServices"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Install log shows this:

```
Action 15:22:27: StartServices. Starting services
Action start 15:22:27: StartServices.
MSI (s) (58:CC) [15:22:27:898]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ServiceControl
MSI (s) (58:CC) [15:22:27:898]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: ServiceControl 4: SELECT `Name`,`Wait`,`Arguments`,`Event`, `Action` FROM `ServiceControl`, `Component` WHERE `Component_` = `Component` AND (`Action` = 0 OR `Action` = 1 OR `Action` = 2)
Action ended 15:22:27: StartServices. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (58:CC) [15:22:27:899]: Doing action: SAMPLE_CONFIG
Action 15:22:27: SAMPLE_CONFIG.
Action start 15:22:27: **SAMPLE_CONFIG**.
SAMPLE_CONFIG:
Action ended 15:22:27: **SAMPLE_CONFIG**. Return value 1.
```

This is my very first attempt to do WIX, so please bear with my ignorance.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

This is a quote from another forum - but he doesn't specify how it works and he doesn't seem to check back often.

> WiX has a custom action that captures
>   the console output and sticks it
>   directly into the verbose MSI log, so
>   that's what I use.

reference: http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=79454

Would this be the tool he is talking about?
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/qtexec.htm
I get this error when trying it: 
 error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'wixca.dll'. 
I have searched entire disk for this .dll and could not find it.

Comment: any update on solution?

Comment: Sorry that was 10 years ago, and haven't used Wix since then.

Answer (score 9):

To enable all possible logging while installing an msi, use the `/lvx* logfile.txt` option. However, even this will not log the STDOUT and STDERR output of command line applications invoked as a custom action.

If you have written the custom action yourself, you can add such logging to it. For example, the DTF libraries that come with wix have a handy `Session.Log` method that you can call. See `c:\program files\windows installer xml v3\doc\dtf.chm`, topic "Writing Managed Custom Actions" for more information.

If you have not written the application, you could write a custom action to wrap it. Such a wrapper could use the .NET [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to invoke an executable, read the [StandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) and [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) streams, and log everything with the `Session.Log` method mentioned above.

**edit**: I don't know of any [standard custom action in wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/standard_customactions.htm) that sends console output to the log. Try the [wix-users mailing list](http://wix.sourceforge.net/mailinglists.html#wix-users).

Comment: See update in my original question, someone told me there is a custom action that captures console output.  Any idea how to find it.  I'll go google some more.  I didn't write it, it's XmlPreprocess from CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

In Wix 3.10 you can use the [Quiet Execution custom action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html) to run an executable (silently, e.g. without a command window popup), and the console output will end up in the msi log.

As mentioned, you need the [WixUtilExtension reference](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction.html) to get access to this feature.