# Where is the file 'wixca.dll' if I have WiX 3 installed

Tags: wix, custom-action

Following the recommendations [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/qtexec.htm) we created a custom action which references wixca.dll. Other places on the net they say this should just be installed with the WiX installer, but I can't find the file anywhere.

I see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052536/wix-customaction-how-to-get-more-info-in-install-log) where someone else experienced this in pursuit of logging, but eventually did not use the custom action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, do you actually need WixCA.dll in WiX 3?  I didn't think that was applicable anymore.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313545/execute-command-line-in-wix-script

Comment: Yes.  I see that the referenced example on sourceforge's site is not the way to do this anymore.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to include a reference to WixUtilExtension in your Wix project.